# Can't boot Win 10 from USB disk

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, usb

I have a Win 7 32-bit system which I'd like to upgrade.
For that, I got a running copy of Win 10 education 64-bit from my university and my plan was to install it on a new SSD.
The problem now is, I can't boot from the USB. It always jumps straight into my Win 7 copy.

I changed the boot order in the BIOS and I specifically tell the system to boot from USB on start-up, but I just doesn't do it.

I tried unplugging the HDD on which Win 7 is installed on, but that only resulted in an error while start-up => Black screen, white letters
"Non-System disk or disk error
replace and strike any key when ready"

I tested whether it's the USB drives fault, but I worked just fine on my Ubuntu laptop. I could boot from in and enter the install menu.

I tried different USB slots on my desktop, but still no success.

Any ideas? I don't have a working DVD drive any more, so putting the *.iso on a disk would take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted my previous answer because I missed some details on your question, and I was typing from my phone which was ridiculous to form my thoughts.

You mention you want to install Windows 10 on a new SSD. So, your question is a little contradictory because you say your problem is that your USB won't boot and instead it boots into Windows 7. This would suggest that you left the drive with Windows 7 plugged in? Where is the new SSD?

You also didn't mention your make and model of computer. Your post (indicating 32-bit Windows 7) suggests that this is an older computer that likely doesn't support UEFI booting. There are two different modes of booting - Legacy and UEFI. If the flash drive isn't created in the proper mode it won't boot. It sounds like the flashdrive is probably UEFI and your computer is old enough to not support that. Your school probably gave you a drive in the wrong format.

Read here about this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode

Check your BIOS settings for UEFI / Legacy mode to see if this will help. If there is no UEFI support you'll have to get a flashdrive that supports legacy BIOS booting.

If you are not stuck on using whatever your school provided you can still upgrade your Windows 7 system for free to Windows 10. If you have your current Windows 7 product key, you can make your own USB boot drive with Microsoft's tools and install Windows 10 with your Windows 7 product key and upgrade for free.

If you don't have your current Windows 7 product key, but your existing Windows 7 installation is a genuine, activated copy of Windows. Then you can't go directly to a new SSD drive. Instead, it is a 2 part process. Using the link below, you will upgrade your existing copy of Windows 7 from within Windows 7 to Windows 10 32-bit. Once Windows 10 is fully installed, it will create a digital entitlement that will automatically activate Windows 10 in the future. At this point, you can put in your SSD, boot from a Windows 10 64-bit USB setup disc and install Windows 10 64-bit fresh and it will automatically activate without product key.

Whatever the route you take, the following site will give you both the ability to upgrade directly and immediately within Windows 7, or to create your own installation media on USB or CD, or even download an .ISO file.

[Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

I don't think the above link will give you an "Education" version of Windows though. If you are set on using that version, you will probably need to use the school's installation media and you'll be stuck getting the USB drive with the proper boot files.

Comment: okay, will try it.
Seems to me, that the UEFI issue might be the reason. What do you mean by "model" of my pc? The motherboard? It's a HP 304bh. I actually don't find any UEFI settings in my BIOS..  (I've got them on my way newer Ubuntu laptop.. so I think this really is the problem).
For you first question: I stated in my question that I tried both variants. The HDD with Win7 plugged in and unplugged..

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the HP 304bh. Rather this is a custom PC or name brand system, please see if there is a newer BIOS update available. I have even seen UEFI capable BIOS updates available in the past.

Comment: strange, I can't find it on the HP site, neither. This is the best I could come up with http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/specs-hewlett-packard-304bh/
Okay, I try updating the bios

Comment: Careful. I would not recommend getting this BIOS update from anywhere other than the legitimate manufacturer's website. I don't want to see you with malware or a bricked computer.

Comment: yeah.. I quickly let go of that idea.. For now, I'll keep tinkering around a bit with your suggestions and see what I can do